# Pagination In Custom FOR LOOP in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-wordpress-pages

How can i add pagination in custom for loop in Wordpress. I have a custom for loop in custom page template and i want to show only 10 result on a page. How to add pagination.

Please find my code below. Any help would be grateful.

```
<div class="vender-bg col-sm-12">
   <div class="row">
      <?php
         global $wpdb;

         $user_meta = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key='yith_product_vendor_owner'");

         for ($i = 0; $i <= count($user_meta)-1; $i++) {
             $value = $user_meta[$i]->meta_value;
             $term_meta = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id=$value");

             $vendor_name = $term_meta->name;
             $vendor_slug = $term_meta->slug;

             $taxonomy_meta = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id=$value and taxonomy='yith_shop_vendor'");
             $description = $taxonomy_meta->description;

             $header_image_meta = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_woocommerce_termmeta WHERE woocommerce_term_id=$value and meta_key='header_image'");
             ?>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 vender vender-all">
         <div class="vender-cont">
            <div class="vender-img"><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/vendor/<?php echo $vendor_slug; ?>">
               <?php
                  if (@$header_image_meta) {
                      $post_id = $header_image_meta->meta_value;
                      $post = get_post($post_id);
                      ?><img class="" src="<?php echo $post->guid; ?>"><?php
                  } else {
                      ?>
               <img class="center-block" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/noimg.png">
               <?php }
                  ?>
               </a>
            </div>
            <p class="vender-name"><?php echo $vendor_name; ?></p>
            <p class="vender-text"><?php
               $length = strlen($description);
               if ($length > 75) {
                   $string = substr($description, 0, 75);
               } else {
                   $string = $description;
               }
               if ($string !== $description)
                   $string .= '...';
               echo $string;
               ?></p>
            <div class="vender-b">
               <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/vendor/<?php echo $vendor_slug; ?>"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Shop Now</button></a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here You can use jQuery pagination.

Comment: this is the link for jquery pagination  "http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/defaults.html". I think this is the best way for this types of results.

Answer (score 0):

Use this where you want to display the pagination

```
<?php $pagination = get_the_posts_pagination(); ?>
```